# Pass json data to spring boot backend

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I am completly new to spring boot. I am now trying to pass a registration form data(json format) from vue frontend to spring boot backend, but the backend always show the receiving data is null. How should I correctly receive the data?

RegistrationController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.result.Result;
import com.example.demo.pojo.newUser;

//import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
public class RegistrationController {
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "api/registration")
    @ResponseBody
    public Result registration(@RequestBody NewUser user) {
        System.out.println("###CompanyName: "+ user.getCompanyName());
        return new Result(200);
    }
}
```

NewUser.java

```
package com.example.demo.pojo;

public class NewUser {
    private String CompanyName;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return CompanyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
        this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
    }

}
```

Registration.vue

```
<template>
    <Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="schema">
      <span class="lblMandatory">* </span><span class="lblExplanatoryNote">This is a mandatory field and data must be provided.</span>

      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="lblSectionField">Company Name <span class="lblMandatory">*</span></span>
        <Field name="CompanyName" class="form-control"/>
        <ErrorMessage name="CompanyName" class="ErrorMessage"/>
      </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data(){
      return{

      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit(values) {
        axios.post('registration', values)
        .then(successResponse => {
          console.log(successResponse.data.code)
          console.log(values)
            if (successResponse.data.code === 200) {
              alert("application success")
              this.$router.replace({name: 'home'})
            }
            else{
              alert("application failed")
            }
          })
          .catch(failResponse => {
            console.log(failResponse)
          })

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But in my spring boot backend terminal it shows: ###CompanyName: null

I edit the code shorter which only contain company name, which is still null.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Yfx.png)

Comment: You need to map the fields to your object. Your JSON doesn't have a `userInfo` field hence nothing is mapped. If you want the text body use `String` as a type instead of your custom type. But I would recommend writing an object that matches your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging your json object before you send it, from there make sure the field name can be mapped to your request dto pojo class, spring boot serialize json object with camel case strategy so if your json body is different, spring will not be able to parse the json body into your pojo class.

Also if you are trying to create rest api endpoints you should use @RestController instead of @Controller annotation.

Here is reference link about [Spring @Controller and @RestController Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)

Your pojo class also not following the java naming conventions, please refer to this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) for further information.

Comment: I simpified the code to only having CompanyName field and ensure the name is matched, but it still null

Comment: try logging the `values` before you post it with axios

Comment: change you controller to @RestController, rename the pojo class with proper java naming convention

Comment: I just rename the class to NewUser and change to @Restcontroller, but it still show null

Comment: can you share the console logging output of the `values`?

Comment: stackoverflow not allow me to embedd image yet so I add a hyperlink called result at the bottom of my question. Also I finally found the reason, you can see it in my answer.

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted as i already told you that spring boot serialize json object with camel case strategy so if your json body is different, spring will not be able to parse the json body into your pojo class.